# What is a good horizontal menu design for a lot of categories?

Tags: jquery, css, menu

Is there a good horizontal menu design to display many categories and sub categories? If so can you give or point me to an example?

Comment: Search google for "javascript navigation menu". It will turn up literally hundreds of results for what you are looking for.

Comment: there is no need to use javascript for menus at all; hover effects can also be accomplished with plain css. see http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menus/iPad-Anywidth2.html for examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you had a look into "Mega Menus"? there is a good tutorial at http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/how-to-build-a-kick-butt-css3-mega-drop-down-menu/ which tells you how to do it (or just copy&paste the existing code).